# how return a new type with an update value

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

If I want to change a value on a list, I will return a new list with the new value instead of changing the value on the old list.

Now I have four types. I need to update the value location in varEnd, instead of changing the value, I need to return a new type with the update value

```
type varEnd = {
v: ctype;
k: varkind;
l: location; 
}
;;

type varStart = {
ct: ctype;
sy: sTable;
n: int;
stm: stmt list;
e: expr
}

and sEntry = Var of varEnd | Fun of varStart
and sTable = (string * sEntry) list
type environment = sTable list;;

(a function where environment is the only parameter i can use) 
let allocateMem (env:environment) : environment =
```

I tried to use List.iter, but it changes the value directly, which type is also not mutable. I think List.fold will be a better option.

The biggest issue i have is there are four different types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're saying that you know how to change an element of a list by constructing a new list.

Now you want to do this to an environment, and an environment is a list of quite complicated things. But this doesn't make any difference, the way to change the list is the same. The only difference is that the replacement value will be a complicated thing.

I don't know what you mean when you say you have four types. I see a lot more than four types listed here. But on the other hand, an environment seems to contain things of basically two different types.

Maybe (but possibly not) you're saying you don't know a good way to change just one of the four fields of a record while leaving the others the same. This is something for which there's a good answer. Assume that x is something of type `varEnd`. Then you can say:

```
{ x with l = loc }
```

If, in fact, you don't know how to modify an element of a list by creating a new list, then that's the thing to figure out first. You can do it with a fold, but in fact you can also do it with `List.map`, which is a little simpler. You can't do it with `List.iter`.

**Update**

Assume we have a record type like this:

```
type r = { a: int; b: float; }
```

Here's a function that takes `r list list` and adds 1.0 to the `b` fields of those records whose `a` fields are 0.

```
let incr_ll rll =
    let f r = if r.a = 0 then { r with b = r.b +. 1.0 } else r in
    List.map (List.map f) rll
```

The type of this function is `r list list -> r list list`.

Comment: I know how to modify an element of list by creating a new list, but I have a lot of list here, I don't know how to get the last list using environment then return a new list with the new location.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you need. An environment *is* a list. If what you're saying is that you need to implement `allocateMem`, then its argument is a list and it returns a list of the same type. Exactly what you're saying you know how to do.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make it clear. I need to update the value of location. In order to get to varEnd, I need to access sTable and sEntry first. That's where I get stuck on. I get confused when there is a list inside of another list

Comment: This is a little clearer but still not completely clear. It truly would be good to start by learning enough OCaml to write the *type* of the function you want to code up. I'll add some code that deals with lists of lists. I hope I'm not doing your homework for you :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot. No you are not doing my homework. This project has 10 different files, this is only 10 lines